# How to change the date format & remove rows from dataframe before certain date R Studio

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 8.8 million observations and I need to remove rows from the dataframe before a certain date. Currently the date format is in MM/DD/YYYY but I would like to convert it to R date format (I believe YYYY-MM-DD).

When I run the code that I have below, it puts them in the correct R format, but it does not keep the correct date. For some reason, it makes the dates 2020. None of the dates in my data frame have the year 2020

```
> dates <- nyc_call_data_sample$INCIDENT_DATETIME
> date <- as.Date(dates, 
+                 format = "%m/%d/%y")
> head(nyc_call_data_sample$INCIDENT_DATETIME)
[1] "07/01/2015" "04/24/2016" "04/01/2013" "02/07/2015" "06/27/2016" "05/04/2017"
> head(date)
[1] "2020-07-01" "2020-04-24" "2020-04-01" "2020-02-07" "2020-06-27" "2020-05-04"
> nyc_call_data_sample$INCIDENT_DATETIME <- strptime(as.character(nzd$date), "%d/%m/%y")
```

Also, I have data that goes back as far as 2013. How would I go about removing all rows from the dataframe that are before 01/01/2017

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.Date` and basic [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)ion are your friend here.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  unformatted = c("07/01/2015", "04/24/2016", "04/01/2013", "02/07/2015", "06/27/2016", "05/04/2017")
)
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$unformatted, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
dat
#   unformatted       date
# 1  07/01/2015 2015-07-01
# 2  04/24/2016 2016-04-24
# 3  04/01/2013 2013-04-01
# 4  02/07/2015 2015-02-07
# 5  06/27/2016 2016-06-27
# 6  05/04/2017 2017-05-04

dat[ dat$date > as.Date("2017-01-01"), ]
#   unformatted       date
# 6  05/04/2017 2017-05-04
```

(Feel free to remove the unformatted column with `dat$unformatted <- NULL`.)

With `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(unformatted, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  select(-unformatted) %>%
  filter(date > as.Date("2017-01-01"))
#         date
# 1 2017-05-04
```